# Change the CSS of JMX Bean output in Javamelody

Tags: jmx, java-melody

Is it possible to change the style of JMX Bean output on the page? I am using JavaMelody to show JMX output.

Answer (score 0):

refernce official advance guide document: "Customizing styles, icons and other resources in the html reports" part.

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Make it understandable.